# installing openimaj's statistic package

Tags: java, eclipse, openimaj

I followed the instructions on this page - http://www.openimaj.org/tutorial/getting-started-with-openimaj-using-maven.html  and created a project. However, it's missing org.openimaj.math.statistics package. I just wanted to use MeanAndCovariance method. How do I install this missing package? I'm on osx (Mountain Lion)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that I really don't need to follow that instruction that basically installed whole lot of unnecessary package. All I need is, download core-math jar file from this link - http://mavensearch.io/repo/org.openimaj/core-math/1.3 and adds to my project. Vola works like charm!